# Write hex array to the file as string in C/C++

Tags: c++, arrays, printf, fwrite

This is a frequently question but I could not find appropriate answer.

I have a char array containing HEX values. I need to write this array in a text file "as a string".

---

My understanding of HEX not being stored in the files (looked garbage data) was flawed. In Hex editor I could see the data.

My Hex array is actually integer array and not characters. This I need to take into consideration.

---

I tried this:

```
   FILE * out = fopen(out_file_name, "w");
   char *in = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * num_encryption * 16);
   ....
   fwrite(in, sizeof(char), num_encryption*16 + 1, out);
```

I also tried `stream` but it again prints garbage in text files.

The `in` array contains the HEX strings like this: `21c169ea622e7d52ecd35423f4c3c9f4`, and there are 32 lines (`num_encryption=32`) in total.

I also tried something like this:

```
std::ofstream outfile(argv[21]);
if(outtfile.is_open()){
  //outtfile.write(wo, sizeof(char)*(num_encryption*16+1));
  for(int k = 0; k < num_encryption; k++){
      for(int j = 0; j < 16; ++j){
         outfile << static_cast<unsigned char>(wo[j + k*16] & 0xff);
      }
   outtfile << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Even the commented part did not work properly.
Any suggestions?

---

Solution

---

I just redirected the output (which was fine) to the file:

```
FILE * out = fopen(out_file_name, "w");
for(int k = 0; k < num_encryption; k++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 16; ++j){
       fprintf(outfile, "%02x", wo[j + k*16] & 0xff);
       }
    fprintf(outfile, "\n");
 }
fclose(outfile);
```

I am not sure if this is the most elegant solution,but it works for me. If you know anything better then please add here.

Comment: Can you give an example of what actual values are in your `in` array by actual int value? And what values you hope to output? For example if you have a int value of 15 in your byte array, are you expecting to see an ASCII 'F' (int 70) in the out?  If so, you need to convert...

Comment: `fwrite` generally won't give you a text file, it moves binary data around.

Comment: I understand the downvotes to this question, as it might be very elementary for most of you. But as long as you are doing it, also write the answer!

Comment: Is that `char` array being used to hold actual character values (like `'2'`) or integer values (like `2`)? That's fundamental difference is rather important to figuring out the problem and the solution. The fact that you show a string of 32 characters but then say a line is 16 bytes rather suggests integers. Try opening your "garbage" text file in a hex editor and see if you've ended up outputting data as raw integer values instead of characters.

Comment: @[TheUndeadFish] Hi your are right!! I opened the file in VIM hex mode and the data is there. I guess then I will have to save the file as char and not HEX integers. Does that make sense?

Comment: Just pointing out something else: one line clearly has 32 characters thus 32 bytes not 16 unless you are writing raw bytes to file. Also not sure why you write +1. I see no reason why you need to null terminate a string in a file.

Comment: Yes you are right! I guess I was thinking about the actual operations I carried out on those HEX integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is about C++ also, let me give you advice on how to use features superseded by C++. You are using C-style features.

You should use iostreams. Avoid malloc, use new, but, even better, use a `vector<char>` or `unique_ptr<char[]>` directly. In this case I will use `unique_ptr<char[]>` since it seems you do not need to resize the array. I assume you want to write a binary file below.

```
//I assume you want a binary file
std::ostream file("myfile.txt", std::ios::binary);

std::unique_ptr<char []> in = std::unique_ptr<char []>(new char[num_encryption * 16]);
if (file)
   file.write(in.get(), sizeof(char) * num_encryption * 16);
```

If you want, instead, write text data in hex, open the file in text mode:

```
std::ostream file("myfile.txt"); //Note, no std::ios::binary
...
file >> std::hex >> std::noshowbase; //Write in hex with no base
std::copy(in.get(),
          in.get() + num_encryption * 16,
          std::ostream_iterator<char>(file)); //Write one char at a time, in hex, with no base
```

WARNING: Not tested, just shown the idea on how to write binary or formatted hex text, char by char.

Comment: What is the reason for the negative vote? I will correct it if needed.

Comment: I did not downvote. Some people just downvote. No reasons given!

Comment: Not really nice assuming this might be oriented towards the solution :D I will be able to stand it anyway. BTW, is this information useful to you? Let me know if you need further help @algoProg